# Reconciling properties of structs and DateTime

Tags: c#, struct

I have been looking through the DateTime structure and I am slightly confused.

My understanding with structs is that you cannot assign 'default values' of fields. If the default constructor of a struct is used (which is not something that you can control), then any fields will be initialized using the default values of their value type.

This is all good and well, but why then is the default value of the 'Days' property of a DateTime equal to 1?  How do they pull that off?

William

Comment: How are you creating that DateTime instance?  Aren't you calling a constructor, which would set the properties to some non-default values?

Comment: A DateTime can be thought of as ticks since January 1, 0001. If dealing with a default datetime value, the ticks are 0. 0 ticks since January 1, 0001 makes the date... January 1, 0001. Makes the day 1.

Comment: `DateTime` [does not have a no-args default constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.datetime).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: No, but as with any other value type you can create a value in C# *as if* it had a parameterless constructor: `DateTime dt = new DateTime();`

Comment: @JonSkeet Nice! I mean... this blows! I'm sure there's a very good reason why this is allowed, I just can't think of one.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Well, think about what array element values you end up with if you do: `DateTime[] foo = new DateTime[10];` - it's equivalent to that...

Comment: @JonSkeet Oh, that is a very valid reason! Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to understand the difference between *fields* and *properties*.

The *fields* are all initialized to 0, but the *properties* can do what they like with those fields. Sample:

```
public struct Foo
{
    private readonly int value;

    public Foo(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int ValuePlusOne { get { return value + 1; } }
}

...

Foo foo = new Foo(); // Look ma, no value! (Defaults to 0)
int x = foo.ValuePlusOne; // x is now 1
```

Now obviously `DateTime` is a *smidge* more complicated than this, but it gives the right idea :) Imagine what "A `DateTime` with the field explicitly set to 0" would mean... the "default" `DateTime` just means exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Jon Skeet is right it's all about the difference between fields and other members. One could really make a "date time" like this:

```
struct MyDateTime
{
  // This is the only instance field of my struct
  // Ticks gives the number of small time units since January 1, 0001, so if Ticks is 0UL, the date will be just that
  readonly ulong Ticks;

  // here goes a lot of instance constructors,
  // get-only instance properties to show (components of) the DateTime in a nice way,
  // static helper methods,
  // and lots of other stuff, but no more instance fields
  ...
}
```

So in reality, `MyDateTime` is just a wrapped `ulong` with an interpretation, and a lot of nice ways to show and manipulate that `ulong`.